# closed/fixed:Interpertation of basic R code

Tags: r

I have a basic question in regards to the R programming language.

I'm at a beginners level and I wish to understand the meaning behind two lines of code I found online in order to gain a better understanding. Here is the code:

```
as.data.frame(y[1:(n-k)])
as.data.frame(y[(k+1):n])
```

... where `y` and `n` are given. I do understand that the results are transformed into a data frame by the function `as.data.frame()` but what about the rest? I'm still at a beginners level so pardon me if this question is off-topic or irrelevant in this forum. Thank you in advance, I appreciate every answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you understand the as.data.frame() function so let's look at what is happening inside of it. We're looking at y[1:(n-k)]. Here, y is a vector which is a collection of data points of the same type. For example:

```
> y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Try running that and then calling back y. What you get are those numbers listed out. Now, consider the case you want to just call out the number 1 in that vector. How would you do that? Well, this is where the brackets come into play. If you wanted to just call the number 1 in y:

```
> y[1]
[1] 1
```

Therefore, the brackets are a way of calling out or indexing specific items in the vector. Note that the indexing starts at the value 1 and goes up to the number of items in the vector, or length. One last thing before we go back to the example you gave. What if we want to index the numbers 1, 2, and 3 from the vector but not the rest?

```
> y[1:3]
[1] 1 2 3
```

This is where the colon comes into play. It allows us to reference a subset of the numbers. However, it will reference all the numbers between the index left of the colon and right of it. Try this out for yourself in R! Play around and see what happens.

Finally going back to your example:

```
y[1:(n-k)]
```

How would this work based on what we discussed? Well, the colon means that we are indexing all values in the vector y from two index values. What are those values? Well, they are the numbers to the left and right of the colon. Therefore, we are asking R to give us the values from the first position (index of 1) to the (n-k) position. Therefore, it's important to know what n and k are. If n is 4 and k is 1 then the command becomes:

```
y[1:3]
```

The same logic can apply to the second as.data.frame() command in your question. Essentially, R is picking out different numbers from a vector y and multiplying them together.

Hope this helps. The best way to learn R is to play around with a command, throw different numbers at it, guess what will happen, and then see what happens!

Comment: Thank you Landon for taking your time to answer my question. I found it really helpful!

Comment: Probably one of the best first answers I've seen on this site.  Nice one!